# How to create Locale parameter in Pentaho Analyzer Report

Tags: pentaho

I created a Report in Pentaho Analyzer using User Console, but I want to add a Locale parameter to change the language for the Report. Suppose earlier Report is in English language and I want to change it into French, so how can I add a parameter to change the Report into French language.